# CSliderCtrl tic labels

Tags: mfc

I have a `CSliderCtrl` and to give the users more information about what they are selecting I wish to have simple text below each Tic to display it's value.

I have done this with simple statics as shown here.

[image: Slider Tic Labels]

However these are statically placed and I am concerned that under different themes and versions of Windows these will not be aligned correctly.

Is there a way to have the `CSliderCtrl` print these labels or a way to get the co-ordinates of the Tic marks so that I can align them correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the combination of [`GetNumTics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ta7xxa55.aspx) and [`GetTicPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7za6s33.aspx) should give you everything you need. The documentation says the returned position is in client coordinates, so this should be the X coordinate on the slider control client area.